# Why did Jesus ask his disciples to collect the fragments of bread in baskets?

Tags: biblical-basis, life-of-jesus

Why did Jesus asked his disciples to collect the fragments of bread in baskets?

As per scripture Jesus ask is disciples to collect only the bread fragments only,
but not the bones or flesh of the fish....

Comment: Does your translation of the Bible specifically say they picked up only bread fragments? Mine says they picked up 12 baskets of fragments. More reasonable to understand that the fragments were both fish and bread   Please cite the scripture and include a quote from your bible.

Comment: Please [edit] this to quote the verse from your preferred translation.

Comment: Waste not, want not. Bones are inedible, and the fish was already bad.

Answer (score 3):

While the synoptic gospels (Matthew, Mark and Luke) are not clear as to whether the fragments were of bread alone (they only mention *12 baskets of leftovers*), the gospel of John indicates that the fragments were indeed of bread.

Quoting [John 6:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A13&version=NASB) from NASB translation:

> So they gathered them up, and filled twelve baskets **with fragments from the five barley loaves** which were left over by those who had eaten.

It is the same with KJV and NIV translations. See [parallel view](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A13&version=NASB;NIV;KJV) of all three translations.

And the reason why Jesus asked the disciples to gather the leftovers is found in the previous verse, [John 6:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A12&version=NASB)

> When they were filled, He said to His disciples, “Gather up the leftover fragments **so that nothing will be lost.”**

Jesus wanted all the leftover fragments to be gathered, but the leftover fragments in this case only happened to be fragments of bread. (The crowd must have really loved the fish!)

And note that the bread and the fish were given by a lad ([John 6:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A9&version=NASB)) and Jesus gave thanks to the Father for them ([John 6:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A11&version=NASB)), blessed them ([Matthew 14:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mathew%2014%3A19&version=NASB)), broke them ([Luke 9:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%209%3A16&version=NASB)) and asked the disciples to distribute them.

The message Jesus wanted to convey was that: What is given to Him will be received with thanks, blessed, broken and be used to bless others. **Nothing of what is given to Him will be wasted.**

Another thing we learn from this is indicative of the principle we find in the life of Jesus: **He was not wasteful**. And He wanted His disciples also to learn this principle from Him.

Comment: A similarity is also noticed in .Exodus 16 : 33

Moses said unto Aaron,

Take a pot, and put an omer full of manna therein, and lay it up before the LORD, to be kept for your generations.                                                                                    Here Manna instead of Bread ..........

Comment: NO its not the answer ,  in both instant Bread and Manna is been preserved in BASKET and POT ?  , There must be some meaning for it.

Comment: The question did not seem as if it was about why **baskets** were used instead of some other container.

Comment: The Question is about Why "fragments of bread" collected ?                              
    what is its  signification.   It was done twice  first time 12 Basket second time 7 basket........

Comment: I have answered the "fragments of bread" part. The question did not ask about the second time with 7 baskets at all. In any case this answer applies to that that event as well. If you want to know if there is any significance to the numbers 12 and 7, that should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

One apparent reason for their gathering of the food which remained(besides what Jesus said in John 6:12 - 'that nothing be lost') might be according to a related speech he gave to his disciples later on the ship(Mat 16:5-12, Mark 8:13-21). That is, when he was exhorting them not to worry about their lack of supplies, he brought up the previous incidents of the miracles of the loaves as proof(Matthew 14:15-21, Mark 6:35-44), and asked whether they at those times had had lack, to which question they answered with silence. Therefore, it is deduced that their gathering of the leftovers had something to do with proving before all that all had been filled, which fact later proved useful in addressing the concerns of his disciples. Also, Mark informs, that, besides the fragments of bread that remained, they retrieved the fish that remained - Mark 6:43.